# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type Int32 but strings work

Tags: .net, linq

I have a class that maps to a table using LINQ but not ORM. It works with all the strings in the class and displays them in the view. However, if I add any `Int32`, `Int16` or `DateTime` I get the error

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type.

With the code below:

```
[Table(Name = "RegisterBoo")]
public class RegistrationBoo
{
    [Column] public string BooNum { get; set; }
    //[Column(CanBeNull = true)] public Int32 ServiceStatusId { get; set; }
```

If I uncomment the commented out line the code fails in the controller at:

```
        return View(BooRepository.Registrations.ToList());
```

with:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type Int32

Most of the columns in the database can be NULL and this is something that I cannot change because I am not DBA. Why does `CanBeNull` not work? How do I solve this error? I also tried using `Nullable<>` and using some of the ideas outlined in the forums.

Comment: Have you tried nullable types? `Int32?`, `DateTime?`, etc. Or `Nullable<Int32>` -- **EDIT** nvm, looks like you have.

Comment: Making the `int`s and `DateTime`s nullable should have worked. What was the problem when you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

`Int32` is not a type capable of representing nulls. `System.String` can, because it is a reference type. To store nulls for value types such as integers, dates, doubles, etc., you need `Nullable<T>`, which you would write as

```
Nullable<int> // long version
int? // shorthand for above, showing shorthands below
DateTime? 
double? 
decimal? 
// and so on for structs...
```

`Nullable<T>` is a struct with special features that allow it to represent null where normal value types cannot. It does this by simply creating a wrapper that exposes a `T Value` and `bool HasValue` properties. When the value is *null*, the `HasValue` property is simply false and it is an error to use the `Value` directly. Otherwise, it is true, and the value is usable.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing NULL in the database doesn't automatically make your C# property nullable.

`string` can be null - because that's the way it was designed by the C# team.

`int` and `DateTime` cannot be null - they always has to have a value.

If that doesn't work, use `int?` (or `Nullable<int>`) instead:

```
[Table(Name = "RegisterBoo")]
public class RegistrationBoo
{
   [Column] public string BooNum { get; set; }
   [Column(CanBeNull = true)] public Int32? ServiceStatusId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
[Column(CanBeNull = true)] public Int32 ServiceStatusId { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
[Column(CanBeNull = true)] public Int32? ServiceStatusId { get; set; }
```

And you'll have to work with the `.HasValue` and `.Value` properties of the `Int32?` reference type.